# Does existence of $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ give the existence of $f_{xx}$ or $f_{yy}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that both the mixed partial derivatives $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ exist at $(a,b)$. Does it imply that $f_{xx}$ or $f_{yy}$ exist at $(a,b)$? Further, does it imply the existence of $f_x$ and $f_y$ at $(a,b)$?

I think the existence of $f_x$ and $f_y$ will hold as to define $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ we need to know $f_x$ and $f_y$. But I am not sure about the existence of $f_{xx}$ or $f_{yy}$. Neither am I able to construct some counter-example to this. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for talking about $f_{xy}$ we need $f_x$ to exist.

For the second part, just take any function $g(t)$ that is differentiable, but not twice differentiable, for example $g(t) = t^2 \sin\frac{1}{t}$ and let $f(x, y) = g(x) + g(y)$. Then $f_x(x, y) = g'(x)$, which is differentiable by $y$ (it doesn't even depend on $y$), so $f_{xy}$ exists (and similarly $f_{yx}$). But $f_{xx}$ doesn't exist, as $g'(x)$ isn't differentiable.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: If I understood correctly, your example also says that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are may not be continuous at $(a,b)$ if $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are continuous at $(a,b)$ under the assumption that $g'$ is not continuous.

Comment: $g(t)$ is not even defined at $t=0$.

Comment: I think one can any arbitrary function $g$ so that $g'$ is not continuous.

Comment: @BobDobbs good catch, I don't know why I wrote $1 / t^2$ instead of $t^2$ in definition of $g$. Fixed.

Comment: @Math yes. If $f(x, y) = u(x) + v(y)$, where $u$ and $v$ are differentiable, then $f_{xy} = f_{yx} = 0$, but $f_x$, aside from not depending on $y$, can be very bad (for example, not be continuous on any interval).

Comment: Still not defined but anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}y$. Then $$f_{xy}(x,y)=f_{yx}(x,y)=\sqrt{x},$$ but $f_{xx}(x,y)$ doesn't exists in $x=0$.

The Schwartz theorem affirms that if $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ exist and are continuous, then $$f_{xy}=f_{yx}.$$

Comment: Hello ! Are you sure of that? 
Don't we also need that $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ are continuous?

Comment: Schwarz and not Schwartz !

Comment: If we specify the domain it would be nice.